# Subset a data frame based on pattern on of the 'Status' column with 'Date' column by the column 'ID' wise

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below, I tried to filter the data based on the pattern of 'Status' column and 'Date' column, on ID basis.

My code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sales = [{'ID': '1', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2017-04-26'},
         {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2017-05-06'},
         {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'M', 'Date': '2017-05-16'},
        {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2017-07-06'},
         {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2017-09-06'},
         {'ID': '1', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2018-01-14'},
         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'M', 'Date': '2017-07-16'},
         {'ID': '4', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2017-07-16'},
         {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'M', 'Date': '2018-07-06'},
         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2018-01-06'},
         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'M', 'Date': '2018-07-06'},
         {'ID': '3', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2019-07-06'},
        {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'M', 'Date': '2019-05-06'},
        {'ID': '2', 'Status': 'F', 'Date': '2019-10-06'},
        {'ID': '4', 'Status': 'M', 'Date': '2019-11-06'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date', 'Status'])
```

I tried following code .

```
df_status = df.groupby('ID')['Status'].apply(list)
dict_st= df_status.to_frame().to_dict().get('Status')
```

After sorting the DF based on ID, date the data frame

```
      Date      ID Status
0   2017-04-26  1   F
2   2017-05-16  1   M
3   2017-07-06  1   F
5   2018-01-14  1   F
1   2017-05-06  2   F
4   2017-09-06  2   F
8   2018-07-06  2   M
12  2019-05-06  2   M
13  2019-10-06  2   F
6   2017-07-16  3   M
9   2018-01-06  3   F
10  2018-07-06  3   M
11  2019-07-06  3   F
7   2017-07-16  4   F
14  2019-11-06  4   M
```

My expected output are 2 tables with F-F, F-M, as shown below.
After subsetting I am expecting following two dataframes.

Explanation:
After sorting, Status sequence  by ID wise will be

```
ID
1       [F, M, F, F]
2    [F, F, M, M, F]
3       [M, F, M, F]
4             [F, M]
```

F-F dataframe after first filtering/subset of parent dataframe

```
      Date     ID Status
0   2017-07-06  1   F
1   2018-01-14  1   F
2   2017-05-06  2   F
3   2017-09-06  2   F
```

F-M dataframe after second filtering

```
      Date     ID Status
0   2017-04-26  1   F
1   2017-05-16  1   M
2   2017-09-06  2   F
3   2018-07-06  2   M
4   2018-01-06  3   F
5   2018-07-06  3   M
6   2017-07-16  4   F
7   2019-11-06  4   M
```

I tried following code

```
df_status = df.groupby('ID')['Status'].apply(list)
dict_st= df_status.to_frame().to_dict().get('Status')
```

df_status is shown below

```
    ID
    1       [F, M, F, F]
    2    [F, F, M, M, F]
    3       [M, F, M, F]
    4             [F, M]
```

after that I am stuck. I dont have any idea to proceed.

Comment: Your question is confusing to me. I don't know what you're trying to achieve. On which conditions do you create the 2 df you want ?

Comment: @IMCoins from the df_status for ID = 1 pattern is F-M-F-F, ID = 2 pattern is F-F-M-M-F, ID = 3 pattern is M-F-M-F and ID = 4 pattern is F-M. So there are F-F in ID 1 and 2. not in 3 and for.

Comment: @IMCoins there one M-F in ID 1, one in ID 2, two in ID 3